# Making a 2d array of queues in java

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception, queue, hashtable

I need an array of 2 tables that are both filled with 256 queues, so basically Queue[2][256], but when i try to make this using a for loop to initialize the entries i get a NullPointerException at the first instance of initializing. I could just make 2 tables but my teacher wants it this way... where we use radix sort by moving between 2 hashtables (0 and 1) while sorting strings

```
public class RSort {
    Queue[][] hashTable;
    int tableSize = 256;

    RSort() {
        for(int i = 0; i < tableSize; i++) {
            hashTable[0][i] = new Queue(); //error occurs on this line
            hashTable[1][i] = new Queue();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have created a 2d array but not have given the size of the array, i.e how many rows you need and how many columns in `Queue[][]`

Comment: You never created the array, only declared it. You need something like ``hashTable = new Queue[256][2]